# Question about quaternionic conjugation

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, quaternions

The quaternionic conjugation is defined by

$$\begin{aligned}i &\mapsto -i\\j&\mapsto -j\\k&\mapsto -k\end{aligned}$$

But since $ij=k$, shouldn't we have that $k = ij \mapsto (-i)(-j) = ij = k$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because quaternion conjugation, unlike complex conjugation, is not an automorphism. In fact, for quaternions $a$, $b$ we have
$$
(a b)^* = b^* a^*
$$
so in you example 
$$
(ij)^* = j^* i^* = (-j)(-i)=ji=-ij=-k=k^*
$$

Comment: @Rodrigo : Random additional fact: Bijections between rings that are additive but reverse multiplication can be called *anti-isomorphisms*.